# Limitar muestra de datos después de usar size en dataframe

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

antes de nada espero ser claro en la explicación.

Dado un dataframe con información sobre películas quiero mostrar aquellos países donde se estrenaron más de 10 peliculas al año.

Me gustaría obtener por pantalla, año, nombre del país, número de películas estrenadas

Yo consigo la lista entera, pero no consigo mostrar solo las filas con más de 10 estrenos, muestro por orden descendente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
datos[(datos.type=='Movie')].groupby(['release_year','country']).size().sort_values(ascending=False) \
  .reset_index(level=1,name='Estrenos')
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Como premisa, cuanto antes apliques el filtro de descarte mejor ya que reducirás el número de datos con los que el resto de operaciones encadenadas tendrán que trabajar.

Si quieres hacerlo de forma encadenada, loc con una función lambda como filtro quizás sea lo mejor:

```
(datos[(datos.type=='Movie')]
    .groupby(['release_year','country'])
    .size().loc[lambda count:  count > 10]
    .sort_values(ascending=False) \
    .reset_index(level=1, name='Estrenos') 
    )
```

No obstante es más eficiente usar un filtro boleano prescindiendo del encadenado:

```
gs = datos[(datos.type=='Movie')].groupby(['release_year','country']).size()
gs = gs.loc[gs > 10]
gs.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
gs.reset_index(level=1, name='Estrenos')
```

o llevándose la máscara a NumPy directamente podemos ganar algo de tiempo de ejecución menos:

```
gs = datos[(datos.type=='Movie')].groupby(['release_year','country']).size()
data = gs.to_numpy()
bool_mask = data > 3
gs = pd.Series(data[bool_mask], gs.index[bool_mask])
gs.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
gs.reset_index(level=1, name='Estrenos')
```